# Android Facebook check in with new 3.0 Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.0, checkin

I could check in with the older Facebook SDK used this code:

```
Facebook fb = new Facebook("APP ID");

Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("access_token", "TOKEN");
params.putString("place", "PLACE ID");
params.putString("message","SOMETHING MESSAGE");

JSONObject coordinates = new JSONObject();
coordinates.put("latitude", "LATITUDE");
coordinates.put("longitude", "LONGITUDE");

params.putString("coordinates",coordinates.toString());
params.putString("tags", "USER ID");

String response = fb.request("me/checkins", params, "POST");
```

But the `fb = new Facebook()` and the `fb.request()` functions are deprecated in new 3.0 Facebook SDK! What can I replace them with? How can I check in with using the 3.0 Facebook SDK?

The Graph API need "publish_checkins" extended permission in Facebook app, but this permission is deprecated also.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the static methods of the `Request` class to create requests and execute them.
Looks like the most suitable method would be [`newStatusUpdateRequest`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/Request/#newStatusUpdateRequest%28Session,%20String,%20GraphPlace,%20List,%20Callback%29) that takes a `GraphPlace` as a parameter.

Alternatively, you can use the [`newPostRequest`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/Request/#newPostRequest%28Session,%20String,%20GraphObject,%20Callback%29) which allows you to construct a request that is much more similar to the way it was in previous SDK.